# LZW decompression in Lua

Tags: lua, gif, lzw

How do I decompress LZW Compressed Gif data in Lua into an array of indices for each pixel in a single Gif frame?
I currently am working on a Gif decoder so that I can display any 89a version Gif animation on a screen without having to use some sort of file upload method to the game assets. However, the only thing I couldn't read just yet was the LZW Compressed data. I already have the LZW Min Code Size and the #Bytes in the image data. I got them from this.

I feel pretty stupid but I couldn't figure out what was going on from other things i had looked up, so asking for assistance.

```
--in a loop for each sub-block
local n,e = 0,1
local max = (2^fbs)-1
--stream is a string containing the reversed binaries in order and combined of each byte in the section
--fbs is first byte size (lzw min code size + 1)
while n<=#stream do --this sub-block
    n=n+fbs-1
    local bits = stream:sub(e,n) --pulls out next section
    if binVal(bits)==max then --checks binary value and increases fbs
        fbs=fbs+1
        max=(2^fbs)-1
    end
    --what do i do with the bytes pulled???
    e=n+1
end
```

Comment: Look at [main working loop](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/pure_lua_GIF/blob/master/gif.lua#L442-L481) in my implementation of gif decoder

Comment: what is going on in the script? it seems confusing